# How to prove that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}: y =0 \}$ is the "same" as $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading a book about complex analysis. And in this book they define complex numbers as pairs of real numbers with complex multiplication and addition. Then they say that we can associate $(x,0)$ as the element $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, because addition and multiplication is preserved. I can verify this fact and I know from ring theory that we have a field isomorphism.

But I was thinking, that in analysis we use more facts about the real numbers than just it's field properties right ? Shouldn't I proof "more" if we want to call $\{(x,0)\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ the same ?

The book I read about real analysis (Kenneth Ross: Elementary Analysis) the define the real numbers as the unique set that satsify the field axioms, ordered set axioms and the "complete" axiom.

If I want to use $\{(x,0)\}$ in the same was as $\mathbb{R}$ defined in my analysis book. Should I just proof it is field isomorphism as in ring theory, or should I prove more ?

Comment: The mathematical definition of "same" usually depends on the context. For example, $\{(x,0)\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ is also isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the only structure that is defined on $\mathbb C$ at this point is that of a field, showing that the set in question is a subfield which is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ is sufficient to establish that it is “the same”. However, if you later introduce additional structure on $\mathbb C$, you may want to check if it is compatible with this isomorphism. For example if one makes $\mathbb C$ into a metric space via $\lvert z\rvert:=\sqrt{z\overline z}$, one should check that this restricts to the absolute value for real numbers, so that the field isomorphism is indeed also an isometry. Note however, that not every structure on $\mathbb R$ needs to extend to $\mathbb C$ in a meaningful way, for example $\mathbb C$ cannot be made into an ordered field.

Comment: But can we make from $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}: y =0 \}$ an ordered field ? I would think yes.

Comment: @Kasper define $(x_1, 0) \prec (x_2, 0)$ if $x_1 < x_2$

Comment: Of course, since this subfield is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is an ordered field, you can *pull back* this order.

Comment: I don't precisely understand why the fact that this is an field isomorphism shows that we can write $x=(x,0)$.

Comment: @Kasper it is a small abuse of notation; strictly speaking $x = (x, 0)$ is false